# Hide app on iPhone so it only shows in search, not as a suggestion in App Library

Tags: iphone, ios, parental-controls

I'm trying to make a phone idiot-proof (or at least idiot-resistant) for a toddler. I'm not worried about content at this stage, but about breaking things.

I know I can remove apps I don't want at all, but there are certain apps that either *can't* be removed, or I want them available. `Settings` is a good example of an app that needs to be reachable but that a kid should never open by accident.

I can remove apps from the home screen, which helps. But the App Library is just one swipe away and shows them in little buckets. Is there any way to turn that off, or make it so that they *only* show up when type in a search term?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use the feature called screen time. You can not only allow/disallow access to certain apps but also block certain content and set time limits for some apps or even websites.

You can access screen time in the settings app. Make sure you choose a passcode that can't be easily guessed, otherwise it will be easy to override those settings. This screen time passcode is seperate from the device passcode.

Edit: I just realized that settings app is not available to block. What you can do however is to deactivate changes in the settings app like changing the code and more. I realize this is not entirely what you are looking for but may help a bit.